# How to declare multiple packagesin web.xml, by REST (JAX-RS)?

Tags: java, xml, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I want to declare tow packages in the web.xml in a REST application using jax-rs. 
this my code of web.xml for the first package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>LampPostZ12</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>lamppost12</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>cuLampPost</param-value>
   </init-param>

  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>lamppost12</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

like that, everything is working well.
but when I add the declaration of the second package:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>lamppost12</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>cuLampPost</param-value>
   </init-param>

  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>lamppost12</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>radar12</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>radar</param-value>
   </init-param>

  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>radar12</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

it appears as it:

```
Etat HTTP 404
```

thank's in advance

Comment: You're using the same url pattern for both  `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` Have you checked for any errors / warnings during startup? Also, what request are you sending? Give more details

Comment: The name of project is **LampPostZ12**, the path of first package is `@Path("/lamppost/12")` the path of method `@Path("/getStateRadar")`.  The path of the second package is `@Path("/Radar")`. the request is: `http://localhost:8081/LampPostZ12/lamppost/12/getStateRadar`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved when I declare in the web.xml, like this:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>lamppost12</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>cuLampPost;radar</param-value>
   </init-param> 
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>lamppost12</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```